# Ajuda com HTML (botão com <area> e <input>)

Tags: html

Boa noite, pessoal. O código é esse:

```
<form action="/teste.php" method="get">

    <map name="image-map">
        <area target="" alt="" title="" coords="210,233,541,508" shape="rect">
    </map>

    <div>
        <font face="verdana" color="white">Player: </font>
        <input type="text" name="nome_player" maxlength="15"><br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="imagens/img_inicial.png" alt="circulo_" class="circulo" usemap="#image-map"/>
    </div>

</form>﻿
```

Essa area dentro do map funcionaria como um botão, só que la só consigo colocar um href, mas eu precisava que isso trabalhasse como um input(submit) mesmo, para fazer o action do form... Alguém saberia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente dessa forma, no `href` vc chama a função

```
href="javascript:document.getElementById('formID').submit();"
```

```html
<form action="/teste.php" method="get" id="formID">

        <map name="image-map">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" coords="210,233,541,508" shape="rect" href="javascript:document.getElementById('formID').submit();">
        </map>
    
        <div>
            <font face="verdana" color="white">Player: </font>
            <input type="text" name="nome_player" maxlength="15"><br>
        </div>
    
        <div>
            <img src="http://unsplash.it/600/600" alt="circulo_" class="circulo" usemap="#image-map"/>
        </div>
    
    </form>
```

---

Outra forma de fazer sem o `href` fazendo um `onClick="myform.submit();"`

```
<form name="myform" action="/teste.php" method="post>
    ... campos do form ....
    <area onClick="myform.submit();" nohref target="" alt="" title="" coords="210,233,541,508" shape="rect">
</form>
```

Comment: Funcionou, amigo! Muito obrigado! Me salvou :D

Comment: Uma pergunta, amigo. Tem como colocar um value dentro dessa area também? Caso eu tenha 4 áreas diferentes e queira diferenciar

Comment: @Flasher12 vc pode usar o atributo "name", mas ele é obsoleto no HTML5 segundo a documentação da Mozilla. Ou então vc pode usar um atributo *custom* tipo `data-value` por exemplo ou vc pode tentar colocar um `ID` ou `Classe` para chamar por jQuery por exemplo. Mas que bom que já te ajudou, se a sua dúvida já foi respondida considere marcar uma resposta como aceita, nesse ícone `✔` a lado da resposta que vc usou, assim a pergunta não fica pendente no site como Pergunta sem Reposta Aceita. Boa sorte com o projeto.